# Getting CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER exception on joining a call

Tags: javascript, node.js, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am trying to initiate a video call with agora and its throwing following error on console, this happens when I try to join the call .

```html
code: "CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER"
data: {retry: false}
message: "AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: dynamic use static key"
name: "AgoraRTCException"
```

I have attached the react JS code here I am using react js module of Agora,and have followed the docs , I have verified email and proper APP created , it worked with the web demo of Agora but not here. Please help

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { options, rtc } from "./constants";
import AgoraRTC from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng";

function App() {
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    try {
      if (channelRef.current.value === "") {
        return console.log("Please Enter Channel Name");
      }

      setJoined(true);

      rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "h264" });
      const uid = await rtc.client.join(
        options.appId,
        channelRef.current.value,
        options.token,
        null
      );

      // Create an audio track from the audio captured by a microphone
      rtc.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
      // Create a video track from the video captured by a camera
      rtc.localVideoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();

      rtc.localVideoTrack.play("local-stream");

      rtc.client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
        // Subscribe to a remote user
        await rtc.client.subscribe(user);
        console.log("subscribe success");
        // console.log(user);

        if (mediaType === "video" || mediaType === "all") {
          // Get `RemoteVideoTrack` in the `user` object.
          const remoteVideoTrack = user.videoTrack;
          console.log(remoteVideoTrack);

          // Dynamically create a container in the form of a DIV element for playing the remote video track.
          const PlayerContainer = React.createElement("div", {
            id: user.uid,
            className: "stream",
          });
          ReactDOM.render(
            PlayerContainer,
            document.getElementById("remote-stream")
          );

          user.videoTrack.play(`${user.uid}`);
        }

        if (mediaType === "audio" || mediaType === "all") {
          // Get `RemoteAudioTrack` in the `user` object.
          const remoteAudioTrack = user.audioTrack;
          // Play the audio track. Do not need to pass any DOM element
          remoteAudioTrack.play();
        }
      });

      rtc.client.on("user-unpublished", (user) => {
        // Get the dynamically created DIV container
        const playerContainer = document.getElementById(user.uid);
        console.log(playerContainer);
        // Destroy the container
        playerContainer.remove();
      });

      // Publish the local audio and video tracks to the channel
      await rtc.client.publish([rtc.localAudioTrack, rtc.localVideoTrack]);

      console.log("publish success!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async function handleLeave() {
    try {
      const localContainer = document.getElementById("local-stream");

      rtc.localAudioTrack.close();
      rtc.localVideoTrack.close();

      setJoined(false);
      localContainer.textContent = "";

      // Traverse all remote users
      rtc.client.remoteUsers.forEach((user) => {
        // Destroy the dynamically created DIV container
        const playerContainer = document.getElementById(user.uid);
        playerContainer && playerContainer.remove();
      });

      // Leave the channel
      await rtc.client.leave();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false);
  const channelRef = useRef("");
  const remoteRef = useRef("");
  const leaveRef = useRef("");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={channelRef}
          id="channel"
          placeholder="Enter Channel name"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Join"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          disabled={joined ? true : false}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          ref={leaveRef}
          value="Leave"
          onClick={handleLeave}
          disabled={joined ? false : true}
        />
      </div>
      {joined ? (
        <>
          <div id="local-stream" className="stream local-stream"></div>
          <div
            id="remote-stream"
            ref={remoteRef}
            className="stream remote-stream"
          ></div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its strange the example related doc says token is optional but actually its needed. Added it and the issue resolved

Answer (score 11):

You need to set token and channel name again in options object because of the expired token. You can generate a new token from  https://console.agora.io/project/
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possible reason for this issue might be that the uid that is used to generate the token doesn't match the uid that is being used to join the channel. Therefore, make sure that the tokens are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using agora sdk and this happens you must try these

> 1. Enable the Live Mode of the project
> 2. Enable Secondary Certificate and use that
> 3. Last and most important if you are getting token invalid or authentication failed error then put 0 in the Uid and generate `RtcTokenBuilder::buildTokenWithUid`

This solved my problem, I hope it helps yours